# ¿por qué desaparece la función después de la primer consulta?

Tags: javascript, datatables

Tengo un select hecho con django y su respectivo boton para comenzar la busqueda de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="">Elige un ciclo escolar</label>
   <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="" id="id_ciclo" data-live-search="true">
     <option value='0' >-- Seleccione un ciclo escolar --</option>
     {% for ciclo in ciclos %}
       <option value="{{ciclo.CICLO}}">{{ciclo.CICLO}} - {{ciclo.PERIODO_DES}} </option>
     {% endfor %}
   </select>
</div>

<div class='col-md-12'>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" id='btn_buscar_docentes'>
    Buscar
  </button>
</div>

<table id='tabla_mayor_carga' class="table table-striped table-bordered display compact" style="width:100%"></table>
```

Su respectivo script comienza al dar click, hace una validación y si lo cumple continua:

```
$('#btn_buscar_docentes').click(function(){
 id_ciclo = $('#id_ciclo').val();
 if(id_ciclo != 0){

     tabla_mayor_carga(id_ciclo);
 }else{
     Swal.fire('No eligió ciclo','Seleccione un ciclo para continuar','info');
}})
```

El funcionamiento debería ser simple, cada que se de click valida y llama a la funcion, el cual despues hace una petición ajax y pinta en la tabla

```
function tabla_mayor_carga(id_ciclo){

    if($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#tabla_mayor_carga'))
    {
        tabla_mayor_carga.clear().draw();
        tabla_mayor_carga.destroy();
    }
    $('#tabla_mayor_carga').LoadingOverlay("show",{image:'', text:'Cargando lista docentes...'})
    $.ajax({
        (peticion POST),
        success: function(response){
            tabla_mayor_carga = $('#tabla_mayor_carga').DataTable({}) /// crea un datatable
        },
        error: function(){"MENSAJE DE ERROR"},
        complete: function(){
         $('#tabla_mayor_carga').LoadingOverlay("hide", true);
        }
    })
}
```

El Problema comienza cuando se presiona el mismo boton 2 veces, arroja el siguiente mensaje:
*Uncaught TypeError: tabla_mayor_carga is not a function*
¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Tienes una variable y función con el mismo nombre? tabla_mayor_carga?

Comment: Tienes razón compañero, cambié los nombres y funcionó correctamente

Answer (score 1):

El problema era que tenía una variable y una función con el mismo nombre: `tabla_mayor_carga`. Cambié el nombre de la variable a `tabla_mayor` y ya funcionó correctamente:

```
function tabla_mayor_carga(id_ciclo){

if($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#tabla_mayor_carga'))
{
    tabla_mayor.clear().draw(); //el cambio de nombre en la variable con la funcion era necesario para su buen funcionamiento
    tabla_mayor.destroy();
}
$('#tabla_mayor_carga').LoadingOverlay("show",{image:'', text:'Cargando lista docentes...'})
$.ajax({
    (peticion POST),
    success: function(response){
        tabla_mayor = $('#tabla_mayor_carga').DataTable({}) /// crea un datatable
    },
    error: function(){"MENSAJE DE ERROR"},
    complete: function(){
     $('#tabla_mayor_carga').LoadingOverlay("hide", true);
    }
})}
```